# How to render <div> tag dynamically in asp.net mvc 4 razor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, rendering

I am working on asp.net mvc 4 razor application using Visual Studio 2012
When i am creating "" dynamically i getting error 
My Code is as below

```
function CreateDiv()
{

   <text>
   var DivContent='';
   var DivContent="<div>";                
  </text>
@{
//Some code to set the contents of div
}

<text>
var DivContent="<//div>"; //This line gives me error

</text>

}
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

```
var DivContent = document.createElement("DIV");
```

This might be helpful,

http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

dont know what you are trying to do with that code you posted . and what you mean saying dinamically . if you mean on client side then you have to use jscript...

//if u mean server side dinamically building html then make HtmlHelper
here is example how to make simple HtmlHelper using TagBuilder
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs